# Grails - using config value for cron expression in scheduled jobs

Tags: grails, cron

```
grailsApplication.config.myJob.cron.cronExpression = Configuration.findByConfigKey("schedule")?.configValue

MyJob.schedule(grailsApplication.config.archiveTablesJob.cron.cronExpression)
```

Bootstrap error...java.lang.RuntimeException.

Its not getting the value from config

How to get the cron value from a table(database) dynamically?

Comment: "grailsApplication.config.myJob.cron.cronExpression"  do you want to pass this variable to "MyJob"?.

Comment: my scheduler cron is working correctly for particular time.But my actual requirement is the time(0 15 14 ? * MON-SUN) has to be taken from database.so i wrote in bootstrap above codes but i cant import my **Myjob Class**. sorry for That ArchiveTableJob

Comment: provide more details and full error stack trace.

Comment: dipak my actual problem is the time values we are giving have to be taken from database not as default value.if its not clear pls reply

Comment: That means you want access the your Myjob Class into bootsrap.groovy this only problem right ?

Comment: yeah absolutely correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124636/discussion-between-varaj-vignesh-and-dipak-thoke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Bootstrap.groovy file set up like this.

```
import com.Myjob          //import your job package
class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
    grailsApplication.config.myJob.cron.cronExpression =        Configuration.findByConfigKey("schedule")?.configValue
        MyJob.schedule(grailsApplication.config.myJob.cron.cronExpression)
    }
}
```

Comment: i have consider that your getting cron expression from database.

Comment: actually on importing the Myjob its showing error (unable to resolve groovy class)